# Reading a NetGear Ready NAS harddrive

Tags: network-attached-storage, netgear, readynas

We had a NetGear RadyNas system with 2 hard drives, though I'm not sure what configuration the drive were in. It died a couple of days ago, and we are trying to recover. We think the drives are fine, and it's the box itself that died.

While we have a backup of all the important data from the system, this is mixed with old files that were deleted 2 months ago, and recovery is being painful.

Is it possible to extract the working drives and connect them to another system to copy the files off the HD?

It's unlikely that we will be buying another Netgear NAS (We're looking at merging our AD server and filestorage to a single system), so moving the disks to the new system is likely to be not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I could only really advise you put them into another, ideally identical, NAS box - anything else could damage the disks and their data. Weirdly I have one in my loft that's not being used and I'm in Dorset - it depends which model you have but you're welcome to pop down and try the disks in mine if the model matches :)